# How to make infinite scrollable images css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I like to make an never-ending scrollable container. The container should include my head image:

My function should get a difference-value (e.g. 200 or 400 or -100) and the images should be moved 200 / 400 / -100 px. (The first image should be moved 200 / 400 / -100 px, and a second -- new -- image should be added to the end of the first picture.

Here for i've created a fiddle:

```js
change_position(50)

function change_position(difference) {
 // move image 50 px to the right & 
  // display next to '| start |' about 50px of the new image (same src)
}
```

```html
| start | <img src='http://kirstenpetersen.de/mal/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/strich2.png' style='left: 5%' width='40%' id='img'>

| end |
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?,  i can not tell if i understand what you want to do.

Comment: Start by making a scrollable container, without thinking about the never-ending bit. Just use a bit of HTML and CSS. Then put some images in it, and try scrolling it. Wonderful. Now simply detect when you scroll to the end and every time that happens add more images. Done! You could at least try the first few steps. If you have, please show us.

Comment: @jonas00, see your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043788/